# Is there a way in apex to add 'force.com Content' files as attachments in emails?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, attachment, contentdocument

I need to develop a way for users to select what content they want from a custom page and then have it added as an attachment to an email. I know you can add attachments to emails via: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_email_sending_attachments.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_email_sending_attachments.htm|SkinName=webhelp 
But unsure how to access/use the force.com content in this way. Is it even possible? From looking at the object in the schema browser is seems that there is no blob field etc that would allow me to access the content and then send it.

Thanks

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25291/file-attachment-not-working-when-attaching-crm-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Content Objects schema](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content) should help here. The Blob data exists in the [ContentVersion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) in the VersionData field..

Comment: thanks, i was just looking at that field, i'll try it and see if it works :-)