# File Attachment not working when attaching crm Content

Tags: apex, email, attachment, contentversion, blob

I have a page where the user selects content (that is 5MB or lower, only 2 attachments allowed per email) to use as an attachment in an email. It all seems to work fine, the email sends and there are attachments in it with the correct title. But the attachments themselves seems to be broken. There is nothing in them, or i get **Forbidden Error 403** when i try to download them.

I have tried it will 3 types of content (power_point_x, power_point, pdf) and all fail like this. also when looking at the attachment in google drive, in the details section it says all three have a type of **Mime type: application/octet-stream** ? I know i am missing something simple here I am sure lol, just looking for some guidance.

Thanks!

```
  List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attList = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
  Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa;
  if (!selectedContent.isEmpty()) {
    for (ContentVersion cv : PromoModel_Helper.findSelected(selectedContent)) {
      if (cv != null) {
        efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName(cv.Title);
        efa.setBody(cv.VersionData);
        attList.add(efa);
      }
    } 
  }

  mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  mail.setToAddresses(sendToIds);
  mail.setReplyTo(replyToEmail);
  mail.setSenderDisplayName(senderDisplayName);
  mail.setBccSender(bcc);
  mail.setUseSignature(signature);
  mail.setSubject(subject);
  mail.setHtmlBody(body);

  if (!attList.isEmpty()) {
    mail.setFileAttachments(attList);
  }

  try {
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(
      new List<Messaging.Email> { mail }
    );
  } catch (Exception e) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
      'An Error occured while trying to email, ' + e.getMessage()
    ));
    return null;
  }
```

**Update:**
So i tried adding `efa.setContentType(cv.FileType);` which created an error saying the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` was **Not Serializable**, so I tried making it `transient`. That created an error around the file type:

```
An Error occured while trying to email, SendEmail failed. 
First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE, An invalid value was specified for contentType.: []
```

The output of the cv.FileType is typically (PDF, POWER_POINT_X, POWER_POINT, WORD, EXCEL_X) and this seems to not work (given the error above, and yes i checked that it was getting the value i expected) So I tried converting it to file extensions

```
efa.setContentType(
  (cv.FileType == 'POWER_POINT_X' ? 
    '.pptx' : cv.FileType == 'POWER_POINT' ?
      '.ppt' : cv.FileType == 'PDF' ?
        '.pdf' : cv.FileType == 'EXCEL' ? 
          '.xls' : '.doc')
);
```

and still no joy :-(

Comment: try efa.setContentType(cv.FileType); ?

Comment: I think you may also have to decode it, as VersionData is converted to Base64. EncodingUtil.Base64Decode

Comment: when i add the efa.setContentType(cv.FileType); the page errors with "Not Serializable: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage" Also the EncodingUtil.Base64Decode takes a string and outputs a blob, and since force.com reads VersionData as a blob it errors with 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(Blob)' So i tried converting it to a string and then when i sent the email i got 'Unrecognized base64 character: [
Error is in expression '{!sendMail}' in component <apex:commandButton>'

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about the decoding part, and it may not be necessary if it is returning a blob (weird that is typed as base64 in the schema)

Comment: right? lol i thought the same thing!

Comment: Ah, dug a little deeper into the schema. It's soap type is base64binary, so all good there. Just need to get the MIME type, which Daniel gives direction on below. ContentVersion.FileType only gives the extension, so JPEG instead of image/jpeg. This should help: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: so when the file is PDF, and pdf gets put into the setContentType it errors, when i try replacing it with .pdf it still fails. do you think i need to do something like [something]/pdf?

Comment: Right, ContentType is expecting a mime type like application/pdf. The IANA link has a registry of them (i.e. image/jpeg, image/gif,)

Comment: haza! it worked! well at least for pdf :-P add it as an answer so i can accept it and give you points lol

Comment: now i just need to figure out all the possible file types sfdc accepts and convert them :( lol but it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel stated, you need to set the MIME Content-Type of the email attachment using the setContentType method. Unfortunately, ContentVersion.filetype is only returning the extension from (pdf, ppt, etc.), and the Content-Type is expecting the top-level media type as well. A registry of the top-level MIME Content-Types and their associated sub-types can be found at http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml, and one solution would be to get the extension, and then manually put the correct MIME Type (i.e. if ContentVersion.Filetype returns 'pdf', setContentType would need to recieve 'application/pdf')

Hopefully you don't have a lot of file types to deal with.

Instead of having a bunch of conditionals, it would also be possible to work this out through custom settings. Apache keeps a mime.types file that has a list of extensions with their associated MIME type here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types. You could make a custom setting for the extensions and their related MIME Type, and then query the custom setting to retrieve the extensions MIME Type.

Comment: well its not returning a .extension its returning things like *POWER_POINT* or *EXCEL_X* etc :-P but yes now i have to figure out all the different types and then what that translates to :-P

Comment: Added a thought on that to the answer. It would take some building out, but would work out better in the long run. Either way it is going to take some work to figure out what Filetype is returning, and then getting the proper MIME Type associated :(

Answer (score 5):

You will need to set the [Mime Content-Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type) of the attachment to match that of the ContentVersion. This will tell your browser/mail client how to open the attachment.

The Mime Type for the [ContentVersion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) is in `FileType`.

You can set the Mime Type on the EmailFileAttachment using [`setContentType()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Messaging_EmailFileAttachment_setContentType.htm).

```
efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setFileName(cv.Title);

// Set the Attachment Mime Type to match that of the ContentVersion
efa.setContentType(cv.FileType);

efa.setBody(cv.VersionData);
attList.add(efa);
```

Also, it may not be strictly required, but you could also set the [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) to attachment for good measure.

```
efa.setInline(false);
```

---

So it appears the FileType doesn't directly map the the Mime Content-Type.

You will need to create a lookup structure to go from the stored value to the correct Mime type. Note that this isn't the same thing as a file extension.

```
Map<string, string> mimeTypeMap = new Map<string, string>();
mimeTypeMap.put('POWER_POINT_X', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation');
mimeTypeMap.put('POWER_POINT', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
mimeTypeMap.put('EXCEL', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
// And so on...

// Should probably check here the the FileType is registered in the map.
efa.setContentType(mimeTypeMap.get(cv.FileType));
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried that I got an error when the email was sent: Not Serializable: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Comment: That error would suggest your code is running in something like a batch. Maybe mark the `Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa` as `transient`.

Comment: weird that it thinks its in a batch.. when it isnt at all.. i'll try it.

Comment: An Error occured while trying to email, SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE, An invalid value was specified for contentType.: []

Comment: and when i output the content type its how it is from the content (POWER_POINT, PDF, POWER_POINT_X). I tried all three individually to make sure it wasnt an issue with one type in particular.

Comment: also i had to make the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage transient not the attachment (nothing changed with i made the attachment transient) I tried both as transient and then just the singleemail and it didnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mark the SingleEmailMessage as transient. Something is trying to serialize it, such as view state or transition between batch runs.

Comment: its ok :-) lol i figured. But so when i do that, it still gives an error :-( *above*

Comment: If they are all powerpoint files try manually setting the content type as *'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'* for `.ppt` files and *'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'* for `.pptx`. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3318355/54026)

Comment: unfortunately i still get the same error :-( An Error occured while trying to email, SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE, An invalid value was specified for contentType.: []